# PHP - $_FILES empty after large file upload on Azure

Tags: php, angularjs, azure, ng-file-upload

I've setup an Angular based file upload using the ng-file-upload plugin (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and I've been handling the file upload with a PHP script.

The file upload and script work on smaller files (tested it on < 1MB), but fails on a larger file (9MB). This leads me to believe that there's a file upload issue. However, I've already created a .user.ini file in the /wwwroot folder with a single line:

```
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

Is there another reason why the $_FILES and $_POST arrays would be empty?

JS Code:

```
Upload.upload({
    url: '/scripts/receiveFile.php',
    file: file
}).then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp.data);
}, function(resp) {
    console.log(resp.data);
}, function(evt) {
    var progressPercent = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
    console.log(progressPercent + "%");
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <h1>Upload</h1>
    <input type="file" accept=".zip" ngf-select="submitFile($file)"></input>
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```
$file_name = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$file_tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

The script fails because 'file' is undefined in the $_FILES array - because the $_FILES array is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: try `post_max_size = 20M` also check if your configurations are being used `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a confusing was of doing file uploads. To set a larger upload size, you should set both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. These can be independently different values, as they do different things.

`post_max_size` is the maximum file size that can be sent in a POST request to the PHP script. `upload_max_filesize` is the maximum file size allowed via **any** method.